# Conda constructor duplicate files warning

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I have a conda constructor yaml file which I use to create an installer to deploy conda to offline machines running RHEL.  I build these conda installers in Ubuntu.

```
name: condaToast
version: 3.7.05

install_in_dependency_order: True

channels:
  - http://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/

specs:
  - python 3.7*
  - autopep8
  - bokeh
  - cherrypy
  - conda
  - coverage
  - django
  - docutils
  - flake8
  - gevent
  - hypothesis
  - jinja2
  - jupyter
  - jupyterlab
  - ldap3
  - lxml
  - markdown
  - matplotlib
  - nomkl
  - notebook
  - numba
  - numpy
  - pandas
  - pyarrow
  - pycodestyle
  - pyflakes
  - pyodbc
  - pyspark
  - pytest
  - pytest-cov
  - pytest-mock
  - pytz
  - requests
  - scikit-learn
  - scipy
  - seaborn
  - setuptools
  - sqlite
  - sqlparse
  - statsmodels
```

This has been working great until recently now I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: File 'site-packages/jaraco/__init__.py' found in multiple packages: jaraco.functools-3.1.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0.conda, jaraco.collections-3.1.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0.conda, jaraco.classes-3.1.0-py_0.conda
```

Which I believe is related to this issue https://github.com/jaraco/jaraco.functools/issues/16, which the package owner is not inclined to fix.

Is there anything I can do to work round this?

Thanks

Comment: the author of jaraco has just updated one of these libraries to remove an `__init__.py`, so hopefully the rest of the jaraco library parts will follow and my problem will magically disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Have updated my yaml with:
`ignore_duplicate_files: True`. In my instance this appears to have not caused an issue with the final build.